# No python installation was detected

Tags: python

не работала библиотека для питона моей версии, решил установить более старую, не удалив при этом стоявшую. Потом как идиот удалил все версии python просто удалив все файлы из папки pyton/python38 и python/python371. Теперь при установке написано, что уже установлено, а при удалении "No python installation was detected"

Comment: При установке чего выводит такое сообщение? Пакета или `Python`?

Comment: @nomnoms12 да, скорее всего. Не очень похоже, что такое выводится при установке и удалении библиотеки

Comment: @nomnoms12, python.